SSH Connection timed-out connecting to a VM via port-forwarding on Windows11
I am on an issue since a while, getting urgent, and not super confident in the Windows sphere. I have a desktop at work that functions as my test desktop. To try software, etc, I installed Hyper-V and runs VM's on it containing the software. I'd like then to contact to those services (be it SSH or web) via my work laptop on which I do the actual work. I try to connect to them via SSH over port forwarding, but always get a timed-out error. I can connect to the VM via the Hyper-V host. I can not ping the machine but this is something that is "normal" based on my local IT. Thank you, cheers.
I have a VM with a running OpenSSH instance. This can be tested by SSH'ing from the Hyper-V host into the VM:
Hyper-V Host
PS C:\Users\u0130210> ssh -p 2023 thomas@10.34.182.46
thomas@10.34.182.46's password:

You can also already see the ports I used for port-forwarding on the Hyper-V host. You can see two ways how I did the port-forwarding, as different tests to get it to work.
PS C:\> netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4

Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
10.34.182.46    8083        172.27.41.98    8083
10.34.182.46    2022        172.27.41.98    22
0.0.0.0         2023        172.27.35.147   22

The listen-on ports are also authorized in the Windows Firewall:
PS C:\> Get-NetFirewallPortFilter |
>>     Where-Object { $_.LocalPort -eq 2023 } |
>>     Get-NetFirewallRule


Name                          : {745714F1-8035-462F-BE70-12BD61838B6A}
DisplayName                   : Slurm VM
Description                   :
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Domain
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : Block
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses : {}
PolicyAppId                   :

But from the remote laptop, I can not connect to it: Remote laptop
C:\Users\u0130210>ssh -v -p 2023 thomas@10.34.182.46
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\u0130210/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 10.34.182.46 [10.34.182.46] port 2023.
debug1: connect to address 10.34.182.46 port 2023: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.34.182.46 port 2023: Connection timed out

I also see nothing appear on Wireshark on the Hyper-V host. Maybe I use it wrong, but I filter on the physical ethernet port with filter: "tcp.port == 2023 || tcp.port == 22"
I am unsure what else needs to be done. Let me know if you need more information. I asked our local IT and there should be no external firewall in between both machines. They are even on the same switch.
Both IP's are on the same subnet:
Hper-V Host: 10.34.182.46/21
Laptop: 10.34.177.213/21

@John I'm afraid this won't work. Putting it on an external network makes it so it gets an IP from the same DHCP server as our physical machines. As machines on the network are white-listed based on MAC, I'm afraid I won't get an IP like that.
